# will sharethis shares affect on fql count_total?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, addthis, sharethis

Dear programmers and developers,

if i put sharethis (addthis) script on my website, and share via sharethis (addthis), will that shares affect on the total_count value, when I do an FQL query?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the shares/likes etc make it to Facebook that count will increment. i.e if a user finishes the share the count will increment.

Comment: in some cases sharethis changes the url to sharethis.com/12312312, and shares to that page particularly. so it doesn't affect to your webpage, and shows shares of sharesthis page

Comment: Do you have an example of this, I don't think sharethis is doing that.. They have a url shortener but that does a redirect